# Almost modularity of Belyi curves and etale fundamental group of non-Belyi curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, diophantine-approximation, fuchsian-groups

Belyi's theorem states that every curve defined over $\mathbb{\bar Q}$ is almost modular (obtained from $\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma,\ \Gamma$ a finite index subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$), after compactification at cusps.

My question concerns those curves that are **not** defined over $\mathbb{\bar Q}$.

Is it possible to compute their (pro-finite? etale?) fundamental group by branching them over the three points, and looking at the finite subcovers?

Is there some kind of a notion of "diophantine approximation" among Fuchsian groups that would work in such a case?